# NSRangeException being thrown when creating a subarray using range

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsrange, nsrangeexception

This is a very odd error that I'm getting. It's this:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {2, 3} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

What I don't understand is that the range (2,3) clearly doesn't extent beyond the bounds of range (0,3)

In fact, it is within those bounds because I set up the array and range like so:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange([wordArray indexOfObject:letterInWordArray]+1,wordArray.count-1);
NSMutableArray* sortedSubArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[wordArray subarrayWithRange:range]];
```

Essentially I am iterating through an array called wordArray, and I want to create a subarray that is all of the items I haven't iterated through yet. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I don't understand is that the range (2,3) clearly doesn't extent beyond the bounds of range (0,3)

It does: the second element of `NSRange` is its length, so `(2, 3)` includes indexes `2`, `3`, and `4`.

Therefore, if `[wordArray indexOfObject:letterInWordArray]` returns a value above zero, the range that you get back would extend beyond the limits of the corresponding array.

To fix this, assign `[wordArray indexOfObject:letterInWordArray]` to a variable first, then subtract that number from the total length. This would give you a range extending from the match position to the end of the array.